# Remove all items from RecyclerView

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I am trying to remove all the elements from my `RecyclerView` in my `onRestart` method so the items don't get loaded twice:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    // first clear the recycler view so items are not populated twice
    for (int i = 0; i < recyclerAdapter.getSize(); i++) {
        recyclerAdapter.delete(i);
    }

    // then reload the data
    PostCall doPostCall = new PostCall(); // my AsyncTask... 
    doPostCall.execute();
}
```

But for some reason the `delete` method I created in the `adapter` is not functioning properly:

in RecyclerAdapter.java:

```
public void delete(int position){
    myList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public int getSize(){
    return myList.size();
}
```

I think every other item in my list gets deleted instead of the entire list.

With a `listview` it was so easy and I simply called `adapter.clear()`.

Can someone please help me fix up the code?

I think I should be using `notifyItemRangeRemoved(...,...);` but I am not sure how. TIA

Comment: BTW: you should be punished for not using `{` `}` around code blocks. One-liner code block is still code block. There shall be no exception

Comment: Ha I'm a noob. what do you expect -- better now ? :)

Comment: Yes, much better :) To find out why it's better to have good habits for you too, learn about programming languages that utilize preprocessor, like i.e. `C`. :) and what bugs this can easily bring for your "enjoyment" (just because you have no brackets :(

Comment: the people here made great points:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no ....
Although, this has not solved my original problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I do not see much good points there. The less exceptions from your habbits you do, the better for you. So putting all in one line is silly excuse due to code formatting tools. For your original problem - I just wanted to comment lack of brackets, not solve your problem. Maybe others...

Comment: Haha Well you're no help

Answer (score 86, accepted):

### This works great for me:

```
public void clear() {
    int size = data.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data.remove(0);
        }

        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }
}
```

**Source:** https://github.com/mikepenz/LollipopShowcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/lollipopshowcase/adapter/ApplicationAdapter.java

### or:

```
public void clear() {
    int size = data.size();
    data.clear();
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
}
```

### For you:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    // first clear the recycler view so items are not populated twice
    recyclerAdapter.clear();

    // then reload the data
    PostCall doPostCall = new PostCall(); // my AsyncTask... 
    doPostCall.execute();
}
```

Comment: in `clearData()`, why not simply do:`myList.clear()`?

Comment: @kip2 there is no method `clear()` in `RecyclerView `

Comment: @kip2 When I first implemented this, there was an issue with the `notifyItemRangeRemoved` and clearing at the same time. I simply check the size to make sure there is an item available.

Comment: @JaredBurrows gotcha. @oleynikd `clear()` is a `List` method, not the RecyclerView's. You could use it alongside/in place of Jared's answer in the `clearData()` method above

Comment: I believe that the items are removed one at a time, and then notify is called so that removal animations can play for each.

Comment: May want to throw a null check on the list prior to the size method as it throws a null pointer.

Comment: I got with a simple way, by running this: 
modelArrayList.clear();  markerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: if you have Generic Array List use this:

data.remove( data.get(i));
myRecAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Consistently facing `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter position` issue with this approach. Hence resorted to using `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 78):

Avoid deleting your items in a for loop and calling notifyDataSetChanged in every iteration. Instead just call the clear method in your list `myList.clear();` and then notify your adapter

```
public void clearData() {
    myList.clear(); // clear list
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let your adapter know about the changes and reload view.
}
```

Comment: This notifies that the data has changed but does not animate the list.

Comment: notifyItemRangeChanged does -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)

Comment: Thank you! This is also a solution for RecyclerView IndexOutOfBOundsException.

Comment: sometime i got exception when clear and add new items in recyclerview. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter position ViewHolder

Answer (score 22):

```
setAdapter(null);
```

Useful if RecycleView have different views type

Answer (score 21):

```
recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

The above line would help you remove all views from the layout.

**For you:**

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout(); //removes all the views

    //then reload the data
    PostCall doPostCall = new PostCall(); //my AsyncTask... 
    doPostCall.execute();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. By just adding this one line anywhere in your code, the recylerview is emptied.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I cleared my recyclerview and added new items to it with animation:

```
mList.clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

//reset adapter with empty array list (it did the trick animation)
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, mList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mList.addAll(newList);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Help yourself:**

```
public void clearAdapter() {
    arrayNull.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this. This actually clears the recylerview completely. I had tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but it was just not updating any view in my case. Of course U had cleared the list first. But below code works fine and clears view of recyclerview completely.

```
  listName.clear(); // clear list
                    
  adapter = new ModelAdaptor(Activity.this, listName);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This works well on onPause - when using with fragments page adapter

Answer (score 0):

Another way to clear the recycleview items is to instanciate a new empty adapter.

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, new ArrayList<MyDataSet>()));
```

It's probably not the most optimized solution but it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` uses `clear()`.

But, if you're just doing it for `RecyclerView`. First you have to clear your `RecyclerView.Adapter` with `notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,size)`

Then, only you `recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void clearRecyclerView() {
    CustomListViewValuesArr.clear();
    customRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

use this func

Answer (score 0):

On Xamarin.Android, It works for me and need change layout

```
 var layout = recyclerView.GetLayoutManager() as GridLayoutManager;
 layout.SpanCount = GetItemPerRow(Context);
 recyclerView.SetAdapter(null);
 recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter); //reset
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case adding an empty list did the job.

```
List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
adapter.setData(data);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have better clear the array-list that you used for recyleview adapter.

```
arraylist.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

just call

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null)
```

according to the source code of Android
this will cause

```
mLayout.removeAndRecycleAllViews(mRecycler);
 mLayout.removeAndRecycleScrapInt(mRecycler);
 mRecycler.clear();

in RecyclerView
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public void clearData() {
    mylist.removeAll(mylist);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help the op at all..  why are you re-setting the adapter? And you should notifyItemRangeRemoved() not your generic notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I should not re-setting the adapter,but I think mylist.removeAll(mylist) and
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() are right;

Comment: actually no. The `notifyDataSetChanged()` should be your last resort, between other performance shenanigans it also breaks all the animations

Comment: thank you,but if I delete some items, and when I do again,I can not get the item right position.what should I do ? 
this is my code:

Comment: checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        item.isChecked = isChecked;
                        if (isChecked) {
                            item.position = position;
                            delItems.add(item);
                        } else {
                            delItems.remove(item);
                        }
                    }
                });

Comment: `
btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (MyPost item : delItems) {
                    focusQuestions.list.remove(item);
                    mHeaderAndFooterWrapper.notifyItemRemoved(item.position);
                }

                //focusQuestions.list.removeAll(delItems);
                //mHeaderAndFooterWrapper.notifyDataSetChanged();

                delItems.clear();
                btnDel.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
`

Comment: Seriously, sometimes the notifyItemRangeRemoved does not work as we want. It randomly keep some viewHolders with old data. So if you want to remove all of it, the notifyDataSetChanged may be the better one to use.