# RecyclerView clear list and add new item show old item too

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

this my adapter

```
 public class MessageAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter1.ViewHolder> {

private List<MessageList> mMessages;
private int[] mUsernameColors;
private Context context;

public MessageAdapter1(Context context, List<MessageList> messages) {  
mMessages = messages;
this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
int layout = -1;

int type = -1;
if(mMessages.get(viewType).getDir().equals("left"))         type = 1;
else if(mMessages.get(viewType).getDir().equals("right"))   type = 0;
else if(mMessages.get(viewType).getDir().equals("typing"))  type = 2;


switch (type) {
case MessageList.TYPE_MESSAGE_RIGHT:
    layout = R.layout.right_message;
    break;
case MessageList.TYPE_MESSAGE_LEFT:
    layout = R.layout.left_message;
    break;
case MessageList.TYPE_ACTION:
    layout = R.layout.message_left;
    break;
}

View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);

return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
MessageList message = mMessages.get(position);


viewHolder.setGroupMessage(message);
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return mMessages.size();
}



 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {

 return position;
 }




public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private LinearLayout groupMessage;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    groupMessage = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.messages);

}

public void setGroupMessage(MessageList m) {


    if (null == groupMessage) return;

    int i = 0;

    if(m.getMessageStatus() == false){
      m.setMessageStatus(true);
        for (String message : m.getMessageList()) {

            //TextView text = new TextView(activity);
            TextView text = new MyTextView(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 2);

            if (m.getDir().equals("left")) {

                text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                if(m.getMessageList().size() == 1){
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left_default);
                }
                else if (i == 0) {
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left_first);
                } else if (i + 1 == m.getMessageList().size()) {
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left_last);
                } else {
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_left);
                }


            } else{

                p.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                if(m.getMessageList().size() == 1){
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right_default);
                }
                else if (i == 0) {
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right_first);
                } else if (i + 1 == m.getMessageList().size()) {
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right_last);
                } else {
                    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_right);
                }

            }


            text.setLayoutParams(p);
            text.setText(message);
            text.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            text.setTextSize(18f);



            //text.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            groupMessage.addView(text);
            i++;
        }

 }
 }
 }
 }
```

now initialize the adapter in my activity

```
public  RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
public  RecyclerView mMessagesView;
public  List<MessageList> Message_List = new ArrayList<MessageList>();
```

onCreate Activity

```
    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter1(getApplicationContext(), Message_List);
    mMessagesView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
    mMessagesView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mMessagesView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

add some data the Message_List

```
Message_List.add(data);
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(Message_List.size() - 1);
```

and the result

[image]

now i will clear `Message_List` the recyclerView must be empty too

clear code

```
 Message_List.clear();
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

result

[image]

here the problem when add new item to `Messae_List` after clear it

add new data now

```
 Message_List.add(some data new); // message i am new data (first)
 mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(Message_List.size() - 1);
```

see result

[image]

its append my new item in old removed item why the old one was gone i clear the list from where it come back

lets try add new second message

```
 Message_List.add(some data new); // message i am new data (second)
 mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(Message_List.size() - 1);
```

result

[image]

now add third and forth .... data

result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This code did not solve this issue :

```
list.remove(position); //remove from list
recycler.removeViewAt(position); //remove view from recyclerview
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

But once you add below line on start of `onBindViewHolder` did the work :

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data).

To properly remove old items from recyclerview, use following code:

```
list.remove(position); //remove from list
recycler.removeViewAt(position); //remove view from recyclerview
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

So instead of Clear The Message_List , Just Create a new instance Of it And

NotifyDataSetChanged That see it have bug or Not....

Or :

```
mAdapter.remove(position);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i will try it now .. and i see it in `LOG` old date not found in `Message_List`

Comment: `Message_List = new ArrayList<MessageList>();`  
`mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`  item still in `RecyclerView` not removed !

Comment: try this mAdapter.remove(position);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this; create a method in adapter class called refreshMessages. When you want to renew message list call this method.

```
public void refreshMessages(List<Message_List> messages) {
    this.mMessages = messages;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mMessages.size());
}
```

To clear all data [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978695/remove-all-items-from-recyclerview)

Answer (score -1):

Call `removeAll()`

```
public void removeAll() {
    cardItems.clear(); //clear list
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

After `removeAll()` you need to init `recyclerView` again.

```
private void initRecycleView() {
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // linear layout manager
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerTag);

}
```

Then populate `RecyclerView` with the data you want.