# How to Parse JSON to change the JSON url on clicking

Tags: android, json

How do i parse JSON in android, that changes its JSON url on clicking.

This is My MainActivity.java;

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL_DATA ="http://example.com/app_services.php?d=";


    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ListView listView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();

    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData(){

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading News...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("category");

                            for (int i =0; i<array.length();i++){
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                        o.getString("d"),
                                        o.getString("dirtitle"),
                                        o.getString("folder_image")

                                );

                                listItems.add(item);
                            }

                            adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override

                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



    }
}
```

In this i want to change the Url of the Json, on clicking. From

http://example.com/app_services.php?d=

http://example.com/app_services.php?d=name

The url's used in this post are not the real one. They are just an example.
And these two Urls may or may not contain Different objects inside them.

Comment: What about making `URL_DATA` not final and just changing the variable with `concat` or `append`?

Comment: make a interface into recyclerview adapter click and add the text on callback of the interface...

Comment: How to use concat or append with my code? Any idea

Comment: How do i callback on click...

Answer (score 0):

When you click a item of RecyclerView to add "name" to the tail of original URL, please just set the following code in RecyclerViewAdapter file.

```
void onItemViewClick (View view) {

   String name = "the name you want"
   String url = URL_DATA+name; //

   /*
    * write the same codes as "loadRecyclerViewData" method, 
    * but just change URL_DATA to url. 
    * If the changed url has the different json format than the original one
    * , you can modify some codes in  "public void onResponse(String response)" method.
    */

}
```

And the following link has how to add onItemClickListener in RecyclerView.
[Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? And how RecyclerView is different from Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif)

If you have any more question, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: i have no idea, how do i do that?

Comment: Did you handle one item on RecyclerView? In other words, did you add onItemClickListener to items on RecyclerView? @ArjunMartinez

Comment: `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
       
        holder.mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String NEW_URL = "listItem.getDescription()";
                String URL_NEW_DATA = URL_DATA+NEW_URL;


            }
        });

    }`
This is my Adapter class. Is this correct

Comment: Yes, right. And add some code to below "String URL_NEW_DATA = URL_DATA+NEW_URL;  

Write the same codes as "loadRecyclerViewData" method, but just change DATA_URL to URL_NEW_DATA.


@ArjunMartinez

Comment: Do you mean that "loadRecyclerViewData" method is not working?

Comment: I mean on click its working.But not updating the data in URL_DATA in MainActivity class

Comment: Ya sure.. But shall i add them here?

Comment: I have shared the codes. Pls check them on ur mail.

Comment: I got the source. please wait for a moment.^^

Comment: I have sent you the modified source files. check it please.

Comment: I think that you don't know how to add callback to RecyclerView items well. So please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif. Good luck^^ If you have any question, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much. It refreshs data. But got a problem. It also holds the old data from the url, whick makes the list very long. The old data should have to be refreshed, so that only the clicked values will be shown.

Comment: Then clean the RecyclerView before putting the new data in it. This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978695/remove-all-items-from-recyclerview

Comment: @ArjunMartinez That is because the old data are always remained when you add new items to the list. In the callback method, you have to remove all elements of listitems before listitems.add().
Call this method, listitems.clear(), please.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It  Worked like Charm

Comment: Plz, check a email.^_^ @ArjunMartinez

Comment: How many apps have you developed. I would like to look into the apps that you have developed

Comment: I developed preinstalled apps for Smart HDMI Dongle, and a few of apps for smartphone.  This is one of apps I built. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innopia.magicsign&hl=ko